# SQL injection - should I put Replace only with String?

Tags: sql, vb.net, replace, sql-injection

I don't understand very well the SQL injection, but I want a simple answer because I only want to know if I should put the Replace (a, "'", "''") only if a is a String or in all the cases?

Examples in vb.net

```
"select email from users where id=" & Replace(myId, "'", "''")
```

and

```
"select email from users where surname=" & Replace(mySurname, "'", "''")
```

Is the Replace in the first case unuseful?

EDIT:

My question wasn't "what is best to use instead of Replace", but if I have to use Replace also with non-string values. Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you use parametrized queries?

Comment: @MyInt no you don't. That first query is wide open to SQL injection without the need for any single quotes. The only safe way to prevent SQL injection reliably is with parameterized queries. Your boss is writing unsafe code

Comment: Sorry, I expressed myself bad: my boss don't let me use anything else but Replace. I'm a novice, so for now I don't have to use anything else. Sorry for the misunderstanding :D

Comment: Plan for your future. Search another boss....

Comment: Suppose `myID = "1;DROP TABLE Users"`. Your replace will do nothing because there is no single quote here. No way to escape the parameterized approach

Comment: Yes, thank you that was my doubt :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL injection works like this:

```
sql = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE id=1;"
```

Now you want to have you ID selected from some form variable...

```
userid = Request.Querystring("userid")
sql = "SELECT email FROM users WHERE id=" & userid
```

When somebody would manipulate the form data userid and send **1;DROP TABLE users;** instead of **1**.

This would result in ...

```
 SELECT email FROM users WHERE id=**1;DROP TABLE users**;
```

It's not easy to prevent SQL injections manually.
Today it's best practice to use prepare statement:

```
Private Sub SqlCommandPrepareEx(ByVal connectionString As String)
    Using connection As New SqlConnection(connectionString)
        connection.Open()
        Dim command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("", connection)

        ' Create and prepare an SQL statement.
        command.CommandText = _
           "select email from users where id=@id"
        Dim idParam As SqlParameter = _
            New SqlParameter("@id", SqlDbType.Int, 0)
        idParam.Value = 1
        command.Parameters.Add(idParam)

        ' Call Prepare after setting the Commandtext and Parameters.
        command.Prepare()
        command.ExecuteNonQuery()

        ' Change parameter values and call ExecuteNonQuery.
        command.Parameters(0).Value = 21
        command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    End Using
End Sub
```

Using prepare statements is the best way to intercept sql injections.

Kind regards,
Boris

Comment: I told that my doubt was only for the Replace but thanks you very much for the little explanation, now I understood :)

Comment: Unrelated, but why are the comment colors messing up?

Answer (score 6):

It's better to use parameterized queries.

eg:

```
Public Function GetBarFooByid(ByVal id As String) As String
    Dim sql As String = "select email from users where id= @id"

    Using cn As New SqlConnection("Your connection string here"), _
        cmd As New SqlCommand(sql, cn)

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50).Value = "id"
        Return cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString()
    End Using

End Function
```

Comment: like above, I have to use only Replace.